# Using Date data type in where clause in Oracle DB, string literal error

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion

So I pull this value out of a column (columnA) in my database:

```
2014-01-05 00:00:00.0
```

I want to perform a query which uses this value in the where clause such that:

```
WHERE columnA = '2014-01-05 00:00:00.0'
```

But I am getting an error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

I assume this has something to do with the fact that it is a DATE data type; however I just pulled this value from the database so I know its formatted correctly. Do I still need to do some sort of explicit conversion to make this work?

Comment: Use explicit cast to date type with `to_date('2014-01-05 00:00:00.0', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.f')` ==> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Comment: or use ANSI DATE format: `where columnA = DATE '2015-08-18'` :)

Comment: @kordirko - you can't use the F format with `to_date`, only with `to_timestamp`. Though that trailing `.0` also implies the date pulled from the database actually came from a timestamp column; or has been retrieved by Java (say) and displayed natively as a timestamp.

Comment: What database client do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` Oracle parameter. It defines a format applied by default to string literals during convertion to date. Different oracle instances or sessions may have own values of this parameter. By default this parameter has value determined by server locale or `NLS_TERRITORY` parameter. For more details see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams137.htm).

For example (SQL Plus):

```
test@ORADEV> select current_date from dual;

CURRENT_DA
----------
2015.08.18

test@ORADEV> alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy.dd.MM';

Session altered.

test@ORADEV> select current_date from dual;

CURRENT_DA
----------
2015.18.08

test@ORADEV> alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy.dd.MM hh24';

Session altered.

test@ORADEV> select current_date from dual;

CURRENT_DATE
-------------
2015.18.08 18
```

The same query in TOAD returns `18.08.2015 18:31:32` because TOAD has own preferences for date formating.
What client do you use?

Moreover look at the example below (SQL Plus again):

```
test@ORADEV> set autotrace on trace explain
test@ORADEV> select current_date from dual where current_date <> '2015.18.08 18';

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 4034615273

-----------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER          |      |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FAST DUAL      |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(CURRENT_DATE<>TO_DATE(' 2015-08-18 18:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Oracle can use its own date format **after** literal is converted with `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (`syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`).

So use explicit cast to date type with exact format or use `NLS_DATE_FROMAT`/`NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` (if it is safe in your case).